# How to add to array when user has done typing?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following array :

```js
const [stock, setStock] = useState([])
```

I also have two input fields to enter stock (this is for different products but all stocks must be added to the stock array state).

How can I add the stock inputs values to the stock array? I only want to add stock when user is done typing. There's only one submit button and two stock inputs.

If I had only one stock field I would've just saved it in the stock state with onChange event but there I have two stock fields so I wanted to use an array.

---

**Edit**: using map based on color and size values to render the stock input for each variant of the product.

Comment: Do you want to update the value of both fields with `onchange` on each of them?

Comment: So the stock inputs are for different products. I just want to add the values provided to the array or is there a better approach to this? What I am doing in the frontend is adding product info and then its variant info like price and stock which is different for each variant.

Comment: I would use an object for this, I will attach an example in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use an Object, on which you can use something like the input's name as the key, then set the state to the value of the input field.

This way you can dynamically add values for each product

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [stock, setStock] = useState({ })

    function addStock(){
        setStock({
            ...stock,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }
    
    console.log(stock);
    
    return (  
        <div>
            <label for={'product_1'}>{'Product 1'}</label>
            <input onChange={addStock} name={'product_1'} />
            <br />
            <label for={'product_2'}>{'Product 2'}</label>
            <input onChange={addStock} name={'product_2'} />
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

##### Edit based on OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74111820/how-to-add-to-array-when-user-has-done-typing/74111966?noredirect=1#comment130851949_74111966);

If the inputs are generated by a `map()`, you just need to find an unique key to use as the `name` and therefore the Object key.

Consider the following snippet, same idea as above, but with `map()` which reders `<input>` and `<label>` for each object in the `data` array

```js
const { useState } = React;

const data = [
    { color: 'red', size: 15 },
    { color: 'blue', size: 30 }
];

const Example = () => {

    const [stock, setStock] = useState({ })

    function addStock(){
        setStock({
            ...stock,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }
    
    console.log(stock);
    
    return (  
        <div id='demo'>
            {
                data.map(d => {
                    const customKey = Object.values(d).join('_');
                    
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <label for={customKey}>{customKey}</label>
                            <input onChange={addStock} name={customKey} />
                        </React.Fragment>
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
#demo { width: 150px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Excellently written, it's good to know that you can also run React in the code editor

Comment: The thing is that the variations input fields are created based on the no of colors and no of sizes using map so im not sure how i would set the name attribute for each

Comment: Don't you have something like an id? If you can add the input map to your question I can show edit my answer based on that. Otherwise, you can use the index of the map but that's not perfect.

Comment: id for the product? Right now I am just using the unique color and size value together as key for the map.

Comment: If you're 100% that will be unique, you can use that as `name` for the input and therefore as key on the object.

Comment: Please see my edit @sash, seems like the second snippet might suit your case.

Comment: I'll try that. There are other values for the variants too, like price, barcode etc should I be doing the same for them as well?

Comment: Depends on the input data. Could you add that the your question? Otherwise, change the `customKey` in my second snippet accordingly, something like `const customKey = d.color + " " + d.size;` might be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You will use an `object` with two keys (one for each input) in the following way

```
const [stock, setStock] = useState({})


function handleChange(event) {
   setStock({..stock, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
}

return (
   <input name="item1" onChange={handleChange} />
   <input name="item2" onChange={handleChange} />
)
```

Answer (score -1):

you could create a temporary second state to store the stock in.

```
// temporary stock state
const [tmpStock1, setTmpStock1] = useState(0);
const [tmpStock2, setTmpStock2] = useState(0);

const [stock, setStock] = useState([])
```

Then update the states on each input's onChange event.
When clicking the button, those two states can be saved into the array and possibly reset.

Comment: My solution works imo if the stock is actually stored in an array. I assumed the user should be able to add multiple sets of stock to the array.